# Selenium - Automate a task

Tags: java, python, selenium

Currently I have a web application where when I give a acct number/ bill number will get all the acct details in next page.

I have 700+ accounts and I need to get address for each and every account.

As this is a repetitive manual tasks I'm planning to automate it using Selenium(I have never used it).

Here are the steps:-

```
1. All 700 accounts listed in a file.
2. Read one account.
3. Plug into the web application in a acct number text box.
4. It will redirect to next page.
5. Extract address for the acct and write into a file.
```

Repeat this process for all 700 accounts.

Is it possible to do this using Selenium. Can I just use Selenium IDE or web driver to do this?

Im very much familiar with Java/Python, so automating should be a problem.

I have bought a course in Udemy on  Selenium but I need a quick jump start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are familiar with JAVA then you should go with Selenium 
Web Driver.
and using [testng data provider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) you can iterate all over data.
Your data provider should be read data from file.

Example of data provider and selenium web driver you can find here:
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/import-data-from-excel-and-pass-to-data-provider

Comment: Both links are working fine. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible by using WebDriver. As you are comfortable with Java, the following steps might help you :

1. Launch the browser. browser related commands are [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/browser-commands/)
2. Read the data from file, I used POI
3. Looping the data/rows enter in text field by using sendkeys.. commands are [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/webelement-commands/)
4. On re-directing to next page, use getText to retrieve data from web page, commands are [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/webelement-commands/)
5. As it retrieves the string value above, you can write it to file by POI.
6. Navigate to home page, as we are in loop, to enter next account. Navigation commands are [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/browser-navigation-commands/)

I have just given flow in normal java class prospective, you can also use TestNG or can build framework etc.. as per requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using Selenium IDE using SelBlocks add-ons for Firefox.
You need to create an XML file for your data.
In IDE you can use the forXml and endForXml commands to read data from XML file.
You can then iterate through your data and perform the necessary actions.
Also you can use the File Logging add-ons for Firefox to write data to file.